# Trying to eliminate duplicates in list during insertion

Tags: c, list

I'm writing a C program that gets CSV format book data as input (ISBN code, title, author) and creates a sorted linked list. The list is sorted by author and then by title. For every book, it needs to keep track of how many copies of the book are input. To accomplish this, I need to eliminate all the duplicates in the list and, every time I encounter a duplicate, increase by 1 the "totalCopies" counter in the book struct. I could create a function that parses the list after all the input is registered, but I feel it is more efficient to do so while the input is being taken by the user.

The function of interest is reported below, and is called upon every time a book's is input:

```
void insertBook(BookPtr *listPtr, const char *isbn, const char *title, const char *author) { 
    // new node
    BookPtr newPtr = malloc(sizeof(Book));
    if (newPtr != NULL) {
        // initializing the new node      
        strcpy(newPtr->isbn, isbn);
        strcpy(newPtr->title, title); 
        strcpy(newPtr->author, author);        
        newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;

        BookPtr previousPtr = NULL;
        BookPtr currentPtr = *listPtr;

        while (currentPtr != NULL && strcmp(author, currentPtr->author) > 0) {            
            previousPtr = currentPtr;
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }
        if (previousPtr == NULL) { //empty list
            newPtr->nextPtr = *listPtr;            
            *listPtr = newPtr;        
        } else {
            while (currentPtr != NULL && strcmp(title, currentPtr->title) > 0 && !(strcmp(author, currentPtr->author))) {            
                previousPtr = currentPtr;
                currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
            }
            if(!(strcmp(previousPtr->isbn, newPtr->isbn))) { //this is the part that doesn't work. it should check if the new book and the one in the position where i would insert it have the same isbn code
                currentPtr->totCopies = (currentPtr->totCopies) + 1;
            } else {  
                previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
                newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
            }    
        }    
    }
    else {
        puts("Error");    
    }
}
```

This is how I'm trying to compare the new book that is to be inserted with the book right before the point in the list where it would be inserted.

```
if(!(strcmp(previousPtr->isbn, newPtr->isbn)))
```

This doesn't seem to be working. previousPtr doesn't point to the previous node like I was expecting but rather to other elements, but I haven't yet been able to figure out what exactly makes it point to them. I would expect it to point to the last node before the position in which the new book should be inserted, as the program scrolled through the list in the while loop, but it isn't the case.

Below you can find parts of the code in my program, enough to reproduce the issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct book {
    char isbn[7];
    char title[151];
    char author[151];
    int totCopies;
    struct book *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct book Book;
typedef Book *BookPtr;


Book getBook() {
    Book book;

    char data[212];

    fgets(data, sizeof(data), stdin);

    char *field;

    field = strtok(data, ",\n");
    if(field != NULL) {
        strcpy(book.isbn, field);
    }
    field = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
    if(field != NULL) {
        strcpy(book.title, field);
    }
    field = strtok(NULL, ",\n");
    if(field != NULL) {
        strcpy(book.author, field);
    }

    book.totCopies = 0;

    return book;

}

void insertBook(BookPtr *listPtr, const char *isbn, const char *title, const char *author) { 
    // new node
    BookPtr newPtr = malloc(sizeof(Book));
    if (newPtr != NULL) {
        // initializing the new node      
        strcpy(newPtr->isbn, isbn);
        strcpy(newPtr->title, title); 
        strcpy(newPtr->author, author);        
        newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;

        BookPtr previousPtr = NULL;
        BookPtr currentPtr = *listPtr;

        while (currentPtr != NULL && strcmp(author, currentPtr->author) > 0) {            
            previousPtr = currentPtr;
            currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
        }
        if (previousPtr == NULL) { //empty list
            newPtr->nextPtr = *listPtr;            
            *listPtr = newPtr;        
        } else {
            while (currentPtr != NULL && strcmp(title, currentPtr->title) > 0 && !(strcmp(author, currentPtr->author))) {            
                previousPtr = currentPtr;
                currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
            }
            if(!(strcmp(previousPtr->isbn, newPtr->isbn))) { //this is the part that doesn't work. it should check if the new book and the one in the position where i would insert it have the same isbn code
                currentPtr->totCopies = (currentPtr->totCopies) + 1;
            } else {  
                previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
                newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
            }    
        }    
    }
    else {
        puts("Error");    
    }
}

int main() {
    Book l;
    Book *listPtr = NULL;

    l = getBook();

    while(strcmp(l.isbn, "0")) { 
        insertBook(&listPtr, l.isbn, l.title, l.author);
        l = getBook();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and [ask]. In particular, your question only contains an interpretation ("doesn't seem to be working") while it omits the observations. Further, it doesn't contain a [mcve], which is mandatory in order to ensure the quality of questions.

Comment: `typedef Book *BookPtr;` is poor style - don't hide pointers behind a typedef as it's confusing.

Comment: In `insertBook` I would initialise a `Book` on the stack, traverse the list and only allocate on the heap (and call `memcpy`) if not incrementing `totCopies`.

Comment: Samuele, this is still incomplete because it lacks manual input. Further, I wonder if you couldn't strip a few fields in order to reduce the example even more. Lastly, you still don't provide the actual observations, which may depend on the input you provide as well, which is even more of a reason to remove manual input.

Comment: Oh, BTW: Find a tutorial to learn how to step through code with a debugger! You'd find the error yourself easily.